Why photons have to choose in Wheeler's delayed-choice experiment? What about human's invervention and photon's perspective?
I apologize as I am new to Quantum Physics and Wheeler's Delayed Choice experiment, I have some questions that I think any newbie like me would also come up with, and I would really appreciate any answers given here.
1. Why photons have to choose?
Why when there is no Beam Splitter at the end, the photon chooses one of the two directions instead of both? Because in the Double Slit experiment, a single photon goes through both directions/splits by itself.
But this does not happen in Wheeler's experiment, the photon has to choose one of the two directions, I expected it to appear on both plates at the end.
There is an argument that this is related to its own interference, when there is no Beam Splitter at the end, it does not have a chance to be interfered with itself so the superposition does not happen.

But why does interference with itself determine this? Why does the wave function collapse in this case when if it appeared on both plates at the end, we still have absolutely no idea which direction it would go?

If I shoot other two photons in both directions (or one photon splits into two) to force the interference happen, will this cause the photon (the original one we are mentioning) to split into two directions to interfere with them?


2. Human's invervention
If we do the experiment on a large enough scale, where we have time to remove the Beam Splitter at the end while the photon is flying in both direction, what happens?

Does the photon split into two directions or does it just choose one direction because it knows there will be a human intervention? Because this involves a third party, the human being, meaning the photon already knows what the human will decide, it is no longer simply a matter of measurement happening to itself.
Or does the photon's superposition will be collapsed into one direction? Does this mean human being's intervention in future changed the past?

3. Photon's perspective
There is an argument that the photon travels at the speed of light, which means that time for it is infinite and the distance is zero, so the whole process is instantaneous, and the photon knows the outcome of the experiment from birth.

But if we slow down the photon by passing it through a different medium, isn't the distance no longer zero? And what happens to the experiment?
And again back to question 2, if the whole process is instantaneous, human intervention in the middle is no longer meaningful (it is known in advanced). Or at least, I can't imagine what does the sudden human intervention mean under photon's perspective whereas everything is instant.

Thank you very much everyone.

In the search field type "user:144747 is eraser".  I have more than a few answers on this.   There is another user Dr. Chinese you can also search who has provided many answers.

No the photon does not split in 2! although many theoretical discussions propose/discuss this.  It it the EM field that interferes, this interference starts with an excited electron in the atom ... even before the photon is emitted.  The EM field considers all electrons in the apparatus at the speed of light .... photons are dumb!

The eraser experiment has been debunked for its FTL claims.... when scientists ignore the EM field they come to silly conclusions.  Many assume nothing is happening in the EM field before photon emission.

Yes humans can change the path of a photon .... if you face a mirror to the sky the suns photons go back to the sun.


In the Mach-Zehnder Interferometer (MZI) setup: There is destructive interference at one of the output ports of the Beam Splitter (BS) which reduces the odds of leaving at that port to zero (ideal case). The other port gets constructive interference which boosts its odds to one (instead of 50%). The experiment demonstrates this effect to be real. While there might be a few excerptions, you won’t see photon A interfering with photon B.

Sure, you can remove the BS mid-flight. All that matters is whether or not it is there when the photon arrives.

Photons definitely don’t have a predetermined path or outcome at “birth”. That is due to QM being “contextual”. There are many examples of this, and most of them relate to “Bell’s Theorem”. If you are not familiar with this, please check out a reference such as:


Plato (Stanford): Bell’s Theorem
Note that there are so-called interpretations of QM that alternately posit that the photon action is predetermined. But there is controversy about these.

Thank you so much for your answers, with your great help, I could put my own answers here, but to be careful, can you please see if I understand it correctly?

Thank you everyone for answering my questions. I finally understand this and I will make a friendly answer for beginners like me.

1. Why photons have to choose?

Why does the wave function collapse in this case when if it appeared on both plates at the end, we still have absolutely no idea which direction it would go?

A photon is essentially a wave function. This wave function is the probability of the possible positions for a photon after it has been measured. 
So if it has a state with a probability of 100%, meaning the position has been determined, it will no longer be a wave and will behave like a particle.
When it is observed or when it has to appear, it has been forced to choose a state (raised to $100\%$), so the remaining possible states are canceled (reduced to $0\%$). 
Just like flipping a coin, the probability of heads or tails is actually 50-50, but the result after the flip is $100\%$ and cannot be reversed. So,
$\rightarrow$ It never chooses but is always in the superposition of both directions.

Why does interference with itself determine this?

$\rightarrow$ In the context of the Mach-Zehnder Interferometer, the photons do not choose one of the two directions but have a superposition in both directions with a probability of 50-50.
Specifically, without the Beam Splitter at the end, it is forced to give a result (collapse) when the process is completed (just like a coin cannot keep spinning in the air forever).
And, with the Beam Splitter at the end, the phase shift causes one direction to resonate and the other direction to cancel. This resonance sums the probability of the two states ($50\% + 50\% = 100\%$). At this point it has actually already become a particle, before it even has to appear on the screen/plate.

If I shoot other two photons in both directions (or one photon splits into two) to force the interference happen, will this cause the photon (the original one we are mentioning) to split into two directions to interfere with them?

$\rightarrow$ This question comes from a misunderstanding of mine from the experiment. I'm sorry and I will skip this.

2. Human's invervention

Does the photon split into two directions or does it just choose one direction because it knows there will be a human intervention?

In the explanation above, I asserted that it is always in superposition both directions regardless of whether there is a Beam Splitter at the end or not. So,
$\rightarrow$ The photon has nothing to do with any action that does not directly interact with it.

3. Photon's perspective

But if we slow down the photon by passing it through a different medium, isn't the distance no longer zero? And what happens to the experiment?

The speed of light will always be $c$, it's just that its journey is delayed when it has to interact with different environments. So,
$\rightarrow$ Even though it is slowed down, it still doesn't experience time, the properties are still preserved.

Or at least, I can't imagine what does the sudden human intervention mean under photon's perspective whereas everything is instant.

$\rightarrow$ Since I explained everything in terms of probability, I don't think the argument "the photon already knows everything in advance because it is born and dies at the same time from its perspective" makes sense.

The delayed choice experiment involves taking a Mach-Zehnder interferometer and optionally removing the last beamsplitter. If the last beasmplitter is there the probability of the photon leaving by a particular port can be adjusted to be any value between 0 and 1 depending on the difference in the lengths of each path and whether material has been put in each path and that sort of thing. If the beamsplitter is removed the probability of a photon going out of either port will be 1/2.
A review of this experiment and some variations on it can be found here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2930
You might think the photon is just going down one path or the other but this isn't consistent with the fact that the probability of the photon coming out of a port depends on what happens on both paths. The delayed choice experiment was a proposal to increase the problems with that position by delaying whether we put the final beamsplitter in the interferometer. So then if the photon was making a choice between going down one path or the other or both it would have to delay that choice until it saw whether the last beamsplitter was there. There is a lot of havering and confusion about what is going on in that paper and I think this reflects pretty well the havering and confusion of the standard discussion on this and other topics in quantum theory. If you want to be confused you can just go along with that tradition.
I prefer an approach in which the equations of motion in quantum theory describe how the world really works. This has the notable advantage of not requiring vagueness or new physics. In unmodified quantum theory what path the photon is on in an interferometer is described not by a single trajectory but by Heisenberg picture observables that evolve entirely locally:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14003
The possible outcomes of measurements of an observable $\hat{A}$ are given by the eigenvalues of the observable $\alpha_a$ and quantum theory predicts the expectation values of measurements of observables: $\sum_ap_a\alpha_a$, where $p_a$ is the probability of the $a$th outcome. There are two versions of the photon each going down one of the possible paths and the the final beamsplitter results in interference between them and if it is absent they don't interfere. There is nothing non-local or mysterious or magical about this. The photon doesn't know anything about the beamsplitter in advance, it doesn't communicate backward in time to tell itself to go down a single path or anything like that. It just interacts with each part of the interferometer as described by well understood equations of motion.
When information is copied out of a quantum system this suppresses interference - an effect called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
As a result after the measurement of the photon if there is more than one possible outcome the two different versions of the measurement result can't interfere with one another and evolve autonomously. So we end up with a structure that on the scales of everyday life looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This is often called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory but it is just a consequence of taking the equations of motion of quantum theory seriously and working out their consequences as we would for any other scientific theory.
